# Sequelize delete query runs, but does not resolve Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have a node js server that is creating and deleting from database using Sequelize. When i create new user in "Users" table, query normally runs and server returns response. But when i try to delete user from "Users" table, query runs but promise isn't resolved, therefore i get no response from server. Here is
my code:

```
const { User } = require("./models")
const user = {id: "...."} //Parsed delete request from client, id is not undefined  
User.destroy({
      where: {
        id: user.id,
      },
    })
      .then(res.status(200).clearCookie("refresh-token"));
      .catch(res.status(400));
```

What i see in console:

```
Executing (default): DELETE FROM "Users" WHERE "id" = '6d3edbab-03b8-429b-b249-a9d3ba6bce7a'
```

And after a while:

```
DELETE /api/user/delete - - - - ms [2021-3-14 14:17:11]
```

I delete stuff from other tables too and they work, so it seems that Users table is somewhat special. Whats wierd is that when i look in database i see that record was deleted. I have no idea what is happening.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by creating a new function that opens a new Sequelize connection and
uses that to delete records in db. Here it is:

```
function deleteUsr(id, res) {
  const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");

  if (!/^([0-9a-z]){8}-([0-9a-z]){4}-([0-9a-z]){4}-([0-9a-z]){4}-([0-9a-z]){12}$/.test(id)) {
    res.status(400).send("Provide valid UUID")
  }
  const seq = new Sequelize(
    "connection string"
  );

  seq
    .authenticate()
    .then(console.log("yipeee"))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));

  seq
    .query(`delete from "Users" where id='${id}'`)
    .then(x => {
      res.status(200).clearCookie("refresh-token").send(x);
      seq.close();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).send(err);
      seq.close();
    });
}
```

Avoid using this function if your input isn't sanitized properly, because anyone who is signed could delete any user if using this. I am taking uuid from verified jwt access token and comparing it to encrypted refresh token, so that user cannot even input anything into the function.
Hope it helped!